# Tabs in email not equal over different email browsers

Tags: c#, email, outlook, dotliquid

In the asp.net (c#) application that im using/ building I am sending an email with spacing between words u use Tabs in the body but they never seem to be acting the same when going to an other email browser.

Is there a way to get them to act the same in Gmail and Outlook of even in Outlook 14.0 and 15.0?

Name:{{ Customer.Surname}}

Email: {{ Customer.Email}}

Comment: ohh and I am rendering the body with dotliquid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format your mail body as HTML and provide a stylesheet that specifies the spacing. A lot more work than just throwing tabs in, but the results will be more consistent.

Comment: Yea i figured that it would be something like this I'll try it tnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but you cannot use tabs to format emails reliably.

If you want to format your emails you need to create emails with an html part that includes the formatting that you need.

Comment: Well that is excactly what the guy before me used to format the email with.. I'll give this a try tnx!